# Lag the date by considering data from another table

Tags: pandas

have a question on whether the following can be done without having to do a for loop

i have a ctry table that looks like the below

```
 CTRY  LAG
  AU    2
  US    3
```

my data table looks like this

```
 CTRY DATE         A     B    C
 AU   1960-01-31   0.3   0.4  0.5
 US   1960-03-31   0.3   0.4  0.5
 US   1960-04-30   0.35   0.42  0.54
```

What I would like to do is update the date column to month end date for each country by the given lag

```
 CTRY DATE         A     B    C
 AU   1960-03-31   0.3   0.4  0.5
 US   1960-06-30   0.3   0.4  0.5
 US   1960-07-31   0.35   0.42  0.54
```

I am currently using a for loop but I am sure there is better and more efficient way to do this
thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using merge firstly , then using `pd.DateOffset`, convert your LAG column to month.

```
#df.DATE=pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
s=df.merge(ctry)
s['DATE']=s['DATE']+s['LAG'].apply(lambda x : pd.DateOffset(months=x))
s
Out[452]: 
  CTRY       DATE     A     B     C  LAG
0   AU 1960-03-31  0.30  0.40  0.50    2
1   US 1960-06-30  0.30  0.40  0.50    3
2   US 1960-07-30  0.35  0.42  0.54    3
```

Comment: so nice and elegant ! thank you ! the only change i made to the above is I used pd.offsets.MonthEnd since I want a month end lag.

Comment: @qfd Yw:-) happy coding